# returning data into textboxes without postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I have a form which has a reference number and a notes field. Something like this:

`Ref 
Notes`

In my database I have multiple rows:

`1234 | Note1 | 20/03/2013 18:44
1234 | Note2 | 20/03/2013 18:45`

I would like to show the most recent notes in my text box. But I would also need to show the reference number too.

I could do:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Connection_String);
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand(Command, Conn);
Conn.Open();
SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();
if (DR1.Read())
{
    textBox.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
Conn.Close();
```

But is there a more elegant solution that allows me to click between each record without postback?

Comment: If you dont want the postback you can use an asyncpostback with the textboxes being inside updatepanels.  But I hate update panels so you could do this with ajax.

Comment: you would want to store the records in a dropdown list perhaps.. also try to get away from using constructs such as `DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();`
you would be better off using `(string)DR1["FieldName"]` instead.. what if the order / structure of the database changes.. also it would also help to see the exact query so that you can order on Date Desc or Asc.. also `update panels for partial postbacks are useful or javascript __DoPostBack` could be used as well

Comment: @dotnetom, can you suggest a good article?

Comment: jQuery Ajax http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are avoiding full postback what you are going to use is `Ajax` (short for asynchronous JavaScript and XML).

You have two popular options

1. Use Microsoft Ajax implementation that comes with `ASP.Net` framework and make use of `UpdatePanel` and other controls
2. Use `jQuery Ajax`

If you have some idea on jQuery library and data structures used in jQuery, it is good to go with jQuery Ajax which is more easy to use.

From [jQuery - AJAX Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp)

> ‘Writing regular AJAX code can be a bit tricky, because different browsers have different syntax for AJAX implementation. This means that you will have to write extra code to test for different browsers. However, the jQuery team has taken care of this for us, so that we can write AJAX functionality with only one single line of code.’

**References**

[channel9.msdn.com - How Do I: Make Ajax Calls Using jQuery?](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ASP-NET-Site-Videos/how-do-i-make-ajax-calls-using-jquery)

Comment: [w3schools - jQuery AJAX Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp)